# HSQLDB corruption after file system resize

Tags: database, filesystems, hsqldb, ext4

I have a fleet of servers running Debian 7, OpenJDK 7, and HSQLDB 2.3.4. I'm in the process of shrinking their ext4 file systems to make room for a second partition on the root disk. In short, this is done by rebooting into a temporary RAM disk which will do an offline resize of the file system and create the new partition layout.

On almost all servers, this works flawlessly. However, on a very small subset of systems, the database ends up with some sort of corruption, causing the applications to throw the following Exceptions:

```
2018-07-25 19:44:16 ERROR h.d..ENGINE user:<uid> company:<cid> remotehost:<ip> <appdir>/appdb/app.db.data getFromFile failed 49485172
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: IO error: RowInputBinary
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.rowio.RowInputBinary.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.index.NodeAVLDisk.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.RowAVLDisk.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.RowStoreAVLDisk.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.DataFileCache.getFromFile(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.DataFileCache.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.RowStoreAVLDisk.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.index.NodeAVLDisk.findNode(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.index.NodeAVLDisk.getRight(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.index.IndexAVL.next(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.index.IndexAVL.searchCost(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.RowStoreAVL.searchCost(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.RangeVariableResolver.setEqualityConditions(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.RangeVariableResolver.setIndexConditions(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.RangeVariableResolver.assignToRangeVariable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.RangeVariableResolver.assignToRangeVariables(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.RangeVariableResolver.processConditions(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.setRangeVariableConditions(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.resolveTypesPartThree(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.QueryExpression.resolve(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:308)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor381.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$ConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:215)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor381.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:240)
```

AFAIK, an error during the file system resize would either cause corruption of the entire filesystem, or corruption on seemingly random bits of data. Due to variability in the systems and their usage, fragmentation on the drives would not be consistent.

Two questions:
1. Does anyone know how this process might cause HSQLDB corruption?
2. Does anyone know a clean way to fix the above error?

Answer (score 0):

As far as HSQLDB is concerned, operations such as this should not be performed while a database is open. If the database is closed, and the copy operation preserves all the bits of data in the files (as it should), there should be no issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.The systems are shut down in a clean way and restarted into a RAMdisk that does everything on an offline filesystem. So indeed, the database is closed. Given that the file systems are clean, I can only *assume* the bits are left in place. I think the origin of the corruption will remain a mystery unfortunately. However, do you know whether or not something like this can be fixed on the fly? Is the only option with the Exception above to put backups in place again? Thanks again.

Comment: You can check your assumption by computing a crypto checksum (such as MD5) of the files before and after the operation. If a database does not work properly after copying, you need to use a backup.